# search box function using redux in react native

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to make a search in my db items but all I receive is the following error: `Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Here is my code where I am creating the search page. JobItem I am using it in jobs page and everything is displaying correctly but here when I put the first letter in the search box I am getting the error.

```
import JobItem from './JobItem';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window')

class SearchBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            text: '',
            data: ''
        }
    }

    static navigationOptions = {
        headerVisible: false
    }

    filter(text) {
        const data = this.props.jobs;
        console.log(data);
        const newData = data.filter(function (job) {
            const itemData = job.title.toUpperCase()
            const textData = text.toUpperCase()
            return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
        })
        this.setState({
            data: newData,
            text: text,
        })
    }
    deleteData() {
        this.setState({ text: '', data: '' })
    }
    _renderJobs(job) {
        return this.props.jobs.map((job) => {
            return (
                <JobItem
                    key={job._id}
                    title={job.title}
                    shortDescription={job.shortDescription}
                    logo={job.avatar}
                    company={job.company}
                    id={job._id}
                    city={job.location[0].city}
                    postDate={job.postDate}
                    dispatch={this.props.dispatch}
                    onPress={() => this.onJobDetails(job)}
                />
            )
        })
    }
    render() {
        const { goBack } = this.props.navigation
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <FontAwesome
                        name="magnify"
                        color="grey"
                        size={20}
                        style={styles.searchIcon}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        value={this.state.text}
                        onChangeText={(text) => this.filter(text)}
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Search"
                        placeholderTextColor="grey"
                        keyboardAppearance="dark"
                        autoFocus={true}
                    />
                    {this.state.text ?
                        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.deleteData()}>
                            <FontAwesome
                                name="clock-outline"
                                color="grey"
                                size={20}
                                style={styles.iconInputClose}
                            />
                        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                    : null}
                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.cancelButton} onPress={() => goBack()}>
                        <View style={styles.containerButton}>
                            <Text style={styles.cancelButtonText}>Cancel</Text>
                        </View>
                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                </View>
                <ScrollView>
                    <FlatList
                        style={{ marginHorizontal: 5 }}
                        data={this.state.data}
                        numColumns={3}
                        columnWrapperStyle={{ marginTop: 5, marginLeft: 5 }}
                        renderItem={({ job }) => this._renderJobs(job)}
                    />
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Please anyone help me with this.

Comment: How you have `export` you component and also how you have `import` it?

Comment: export default JobList and is inported on the top as you can see

Comment: you forgot to export your component ...

Comment: If I use that component in JobsList.js how can I forgot to export it?

Comment: Well you have exported `JobList ` as per your comment, but in question you have imported `JobItem`, is this in the question only?

Comment: My mistake sorry `JobItem` . I use `JobItem` in `JobList`

Comment: The conditional rendering in you code is `{ this.state.text ?` part, the way you have used it look fine to me. Can you please remove this conditional rendering and check whether u face same error or not (for debuggin purpose only).

Comment: @PrasunPal Ok so I just realised that something is going when on this line from filter funciton `return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1
            console.log(itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1)` if I comment the return line then I get the console.log otherwise I get that error